# Object is undefined when I call it from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, javascript-objects

I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

It is in line 29 when I invoke the function `listView.render()`

Thanks for the help

```
var model =  {
    // the array with cats names
    cats: ['mew', 'meo', 'meaw', 'memaw', 'mesaw', 'metaw'],
    // The array of cats objects
    Cats: []
    }


var oct = {
    // selecting the list on the left of the container
    catsList: function () {
         return document.querySelector('#catsList');
    },
    //selecting the cat display div
    catsDisplay: function () {
         return document.querySelector('#catsDisplay');
    },
     // creating the Cat object and push it to the Cats array
    addCat: (function (arr) {
         for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            model.Cats.push((function (n) {
                return {
                name: n,
                photo: n + '.jpg',
                score: 0
                };
             }(arr[i])));
     listView.render(model.Cats[i]);
         };
    }(model.cats))
}

var listView = {
    render: function (CatObj) {
         oct.CatList.innerHTML = "<div id='"+CatObj.addCat.name+"'>ss</div>"
    }
}
```

Comment: The `addCat` code is wrapped in an IIFE and therefore executes right away. That's a very bad design and quite unexpected and also why `listView` is undefined at that point. You should at least have something like `oct.init()` that would kick things off. Your whole code is actually quite bad IMO (no offense), with tight coupling and hidden dependencies everywhere. For instance, why listView doesn't encapsulate it's own list DOM element... you wouldn't have to reach into oct from there.

Answer (score 0):

`listView` is being hoisted and is set to `undefined`. so here 
`listView.render(model.Cats[i]);` , `listView`  is `undefined`

Comment: That's true, but the real problem is the IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use listView before you declare it. Try this instead:

```
var model =  {
    // the array with cats names
    cats: ['mew', 'meo', 'meaw', 'memaw', 'mesaw', 'metaw'],
    // The array of cats objects
    Cats: []
    }


var listView = {
    render: function (CatObj) {
         //oct.CatList.innerHTML = "<div id='"+CatObj.addCat.name+"'>ss</div>"
    }
}


var oct = {
    // selecting the list on the left of the container
    catsList: function () {
         return document.querySelector('#catsList');
    },
    //selecting the cat display div
    catsDisplay: function () {
         return document.querySelector('#catsDisplay');
    },
     // creating the Cat object and push it to the Cats array
    addCat: (function (arr) {
         for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            model.Cats.push((function (n) {
                return {
                name: n,
                photo: n + '.jpg',
                score: 0
                };
             }(arr[i])));
     listView.render(model.Cats[i]);
         };
    }(model.cats))
}

    var listView = {
    render: function (CatObj) {
         oct.CatList.innerHTML = "<div id='"+CatObj.addCat.name+"'>ss</div>"
    }
}
```

Comment: By that notion, wouldn't `oct` be undefined now?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare functions as variables, they're created in their place so in this case you've declared listView after you're calling it

If you want listView to be available regardless of where it is change it to a regular function like

```
function listView() {

}
```

As functions will be hoisted to the top during run time.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a property named `CatList` at `oct` object . You are also not calling the function. Try substituting `oct.catsList` for `oct.CatList` , calling function. Also changed `Cats` to `_Cats` , replaced IIFE with returning a function that could be called

```js
var model = {
  // the array with cats names
  cats: ['mew', 'meo', 'meaw', 'memaw', 'mesaw', 'metaw'],
  // The array of cats objects
  _Cats: []
}

var oct = {
  // selecting the list on the left of the container
  catsList: function() {
    return document.querySelector('#catsList');
  },
  //selecting the cat display div
  catsDisplay: function() {
    return document.querySelector('#catsDisplay');
  },
  // creating the Cat object and push it to the Cats array
  addCat: (function(arr) {
    return function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        model._Cats.push({
          name: i,
          photo: i + '.jpg',
          score: 0
        });
        listView.render(model._Cats[i]);
      };
    }
  }(model.cats))
}

var listView = {
  render: function(CatObj) {
    oct.catsList().innerHTML += "<div id='" + CatObj.name + "'>ss</div>"
  }
}

oct.addCat()
```

```html
<div id="catsList">

</div>

<div id="catsDisplay">

</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8u60bcsv/1/